# Do browser tabs share TCP connections?

Tags: browser, browser-tabs

Context: Applying load balance to requests from different tabs. It would be simpler to implement if any browser's connection would carry requests from only a single tab. It would be even better if there was a standard or RFC dealing with this.

Comment: What the heck are you trying to achieve? To the best of my knowledge each request from a single tab is a completely new request to a server. If the load balancer does some basic round-robin load balancing, then the chance of multiple tabs having different connections to different back-end machines in the load balancer are high. But if the load balancer delivers based on other criteria, like purely IP address or geographic location, then all the connections would be from the same band-end source. But I doubt they would share a TCP connection. The only thing “shared” I know of would be cookies.

Comment: first, take into account the "connection: keep-alive" header (which is the default in HTTP/1.1): one TCP connection can deliver several requests to the server ... then: in fact I think tabs **do** share TCP connections, as stated [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-dev/c/S3TEvmRWcNE/m/T7ZwPWa8CQAJ?pli=1) ... I'm looking for a more solid confirmation ... also, a colleague of mine says that cookies can be created by client JS in one tab, and they would not be shared across the browser with other tabs

Comment: “…also, a colleague of mine says that cookies can be created by client JS in one tab, and they would not be shared across the browser with other tabs.” You need to stop listening to your colleague. Check [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/161111/21196) as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39369037/117259), “That’s not possible since a cookie are defined by a path, that means that all browser tabs and windows by one user share the same cookie.”

Comment: clarification: the clieny JS in one tab can explicitly send a `cookie:` header with something that's not necessarily a " real" browser cookie

Comment: None of this matters. The problem with this question is you are presenting an idea, but not explaining what the core issue you believe you are addressing is. What you describe is done by 100% of nobody. End of my comments here.

Comment: wow, I asked a simple question ... unfortunately I couldn't make myself be understood ... no sweat here, but I think you're being over-reactive

Answer (score -2):

Browser tabs do not (by any reasonable measure) share TCP connections, you could however route alternate browsers through different network adaptors.

Different browsers being for example, Chrome/Firefox, Firefox portable and regular Firefox, or any other winning combination.

ForceBindIP can apparently achieve this on Windows, though I've not used it myself.

Comment: please see my comment above ... and: by "tabs share TCP connections" I mean the browser as a whole opens several parallel conections to a server domain, and when any window or tab needs to send a request to that domain, that request can travel in any connection of those parallel connections previously opened ... at least, that's my assumption, that I'm trying to corroborate

Comment: The link states that a tab *may* use a socket in the pool.
Not 'may' like it is allowed to, 'may' like it might, or might not.
May like it may use the same port, given one port must be picked from the thousands available.

It is not something that can be relied upon or expected outside very specific circumstances.

Being highly conditional is why we're trying to figure out what you are trying to achieve.
What is resolved by load balancing different tabs?
How do you think socket sharing can influence the desired outcome?